# How to view COM ports on Android device?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, arduino-uno

I am trying to connect to my Arduino via HC-05 Bluetooth module. I made a simple Unity app that connects to it and works fine on PC. However, I can't connect to the module via Android device. In my opinion, the problem is related with COM ports: ports on PC and Android device are not the similar. So, I need to get COM ports on my Android device. Is it possible? How can I view it?

Comment: https://github.com/cvasquez-github/unity-android-serial-arduino

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get COM ports on an android device. What you could do though is connect your phone to your pc to stream the game from unity on you pc to your phone. Head to Edit > Project Settings > Editor and set the first dropdown menu to "Any android device" (the menu is underneath where it says "unity remote"). Then go onto your android phone and go to Settings > About Phone > Software Information and tap on build number 7 times. This will enable developer mode. then head into the developer options menu and enable usb debugging (it might take a while to find the option). then download unity remote 5 on your android device, open it, connect your phone to your computer via usb and then go to unity and run it. it should be synced to your phone.

hope this helps!

Comment: Well, I want to create a single mobile app, so this is not really what I want to achieve. However, thank you for your help, really wise move =)